# how to retrieve specific users in swipe refresh layout

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, swiperefreshlayout

I am creating a matrimony application and using firebase as database, in which first fragment is search profile.In search profile it shows all the profiles from database may it be male or female but I want to show male profiles for female user and vice versa. And every user is authenticated user.
  I have tried different queries but did'nt succeed. Please help to figure out the issue.

These are users in firebase:

[image: These are users in firebase]

These are the fields in every user:

[image: These are the fields in every user]

Below is the code for search profile:

```
public class Search_fragment extends Fragment {

    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Firebase firebase;
   // List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Boolean isScrolling = false;
    Context context;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    Button filter;
    FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<User, UserViewHolder> adapter;
    User user10=new User();
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    public Search_fragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.search__profile, container, false);

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();

        String authgender=user10.getGender();


        filter=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button9);
        filter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it=new Intent(getActivity(),FilterMain.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }
        });

        mSwipeRefreshLayout =view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPrefetchDistance(2)
                .setPageSize(1)
                .build();


        DatabasePagingOptions<User> options = new DatabasePagingOptions.Builder<User>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(databaseReference, config, User.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new UserViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler, parent, false),context) {
                };
            }
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UserViewHolder viewHolder, final int i, @NonNull final User user) {

                viewHolder.setItem(user, i);


                int newPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

            }
            @Override
            protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
                switch (state) {
                    case LOADING_INITIAL:
                    case LOADING_MORE:
                        // Do your loading animation
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                        break;

                    case LOADED:
                        // Stop Animation
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;

                    case FINISHED:
                        //Reached end of Data set
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;

                    case ERROR:
                        retry();
                        break;
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void onError(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                super.onError(databaseError);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                databaseError.toException().printStackTrace();
                // Handle Error
                retry();
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                adapter.refresh();
            }
        });
return view;
    }
}
```

Below is code for UserViewHolder:

```
class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Firebase firebase;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    List<User> MainImageUploadInfoList;
    ImageView imageView,invite;
    CircleImageView shortlist;
    public TextView FirstNameTextView;
    public TextView DateTextView;
    public TextView HeightTextView;
    public TextView EducationTextView;
    public TextView OccupationTextView;
    public TextView UserIDTextView;
    public Button send_invitation,shortlist_profile;
    public TextView income;
    public TextView city_state;
    public TextView hobbies;
    public TextView marital_status;
    public TextView family_members;
    public TextView mothers_name;
    public TextView fathers_name;
    public TextView fathers_occupation;
    public TextView mothers_occupation;
    public TextView gendertv;
    public CardView mCardView;
    String sluidgl,sluidtemp;
    public List<User> mUploads;
    int flag=0;
    HashSet<String> set=new HashSet<String>();

    User user=new User();
    private final Context context;
    // private Object Context;

    public UserViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView, final Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        this.context=context;

        itemView.setTag(user.getUser_id());
        mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview1);
        FirstNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        DateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        HeightTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        EducationTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        OccupationTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        UserIDTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        income = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.income);
        city_state = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_state);
        hobbies = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hobbies);
        marital_status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.marital_status);
        family_members = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.family_members);
        mothers_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mothers_name);
        fathers_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fathers_name);
        fathers_occupation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fathers_occupation);
        mothers_occupation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mothers_occupation);
        gendertv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        shortlist=(CircleImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.shortlisted);
        invite=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.invite);

 mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int i = (int) itemView.getTag();

                for(i=0;i<=0;i++){
                    final Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                    it.putExtra("first_name", FirstNameTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("date", DateTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("height", HeightTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("city_state", city_state.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("hobbies", hobbies.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("highest_education", EducationTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("occupation", OccupationTextView.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("income", income.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("marital_status", marital_status.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("family_members", family_members.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("fathers_name", fathers_name.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("mothers_name", mothers_name.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", fathers_occupation.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", mothers_occupation.getText().toString());
                    it.putExtra("user_id", UserIDTextView.getText().toString());
                    imageView.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
                    it.putExtra("profile_image",bitmap);
                    it.putExtra("positionGroup", i);
                    itemView.getContext().startActivity(it);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void setItem(final User user, final int i){
mCardView.setTag(i);
                    FirstNameTextView.setText(user.getFirst_name() + " " + user.getLast_name());
                    DateTextView.setText(user.getDate());
                    HeightTextView.setText(user.getHeight());
                    EducationTextView.setText(user.getHighest_education());
                    OccupationTextView.setText(user.getOccupation());
                    UserIDTextView.setText(user.getUser_id());
                    income.setText(user.getIncome());
                    city_state.setText(user.getCity_state());
                    hobbies.setText(user.getHobbies());
                    marital_status.setText(user.getMarital_status());
                    family_members.setText(user.getFamily_members());
                    mothers_name.setText(user.getMothers_name());
                    fathers_name.setText(user.getFathers_name());
                    fathers_occupation.setText(user.getFathers_occupation());
                    mothers_occupation.setText(user.getMothers_occupation());
                    gendertv.setText(user.getGender());
                    Picasso.get().load(user.getMainImage()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).fit().into(imageView);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "gender"' at User/User to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance
W/System.err: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Data not found at given child path!
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:229)
W/System.err:     at accentra.in.Search_fragment$2.onError(Search_fragment.java:142)
        at com.shreyaspatil.firebase.recyclerpagination.FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter$4.onChanged(FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter.java:76)
W/System.err:     at com.shreyaspatil.firebase.recyclerpagination.FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter$4.onChanged(FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter.java:73)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
W/System.err:     at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
W/System.err:     at androidx.lifecycle.Transformations$2$1.onChanged(Transformations.java:155)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.onChanged(MediatorLiveData.java:152)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
W/System.err:     at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
W/System.err:     at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
W/FirebaseDataSource: retry() not valid when in state: LOADING_INITIAL
```

Comment: Where is the query which you used to for search?

Comment: @AmanB. Query query=databaseReference.child(mAuth.getUid()).orderByChild("gender"); This is the query which I have tried                                  
 DatabasePagingOptions<User> options = new DatabasePagingOptions.Builder<User>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(query, config, User.class)
                .build();

Comment: This query is targeting the child node of user who is logged in ie mAuth.getUid(), you need to change this to "User" node to get all children sorted by gender. So the query would be Query query=databaseReference.child("Users").orderByChild("gender");                                     Do let me know if this is correct, I'll put it up as answer.

Comment: @AmanB. So can you tell me what query should I pass please.

Comment: Already told in the previous comment.

Comment: @AmanB. After applying your query it does'nt give output an shows above edit part in run console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208482/discussion-between-aman-b-and-reetu-jaiswal).

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the users with different gender in your firebase query.

Based on your data you can apply the following query:

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").orderByChild("gender").equalTo("REQUIRED_GENDER_HERE");`

Pass this data to your view and it should work. In your case since your are using firebase wrapper on recycler view, updating the query in your code should be enough.

For warning of index not present in your db on gender, you need to specify index in firebase rules. Have a look at the documentation for rules here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Comment: It is giving a error as java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't call startAt() or equalTo() multiple times –

Comment: I think this is happening due to use of pagination option of firebase recycler. You will either need to remove pagination or filter the results manually. Since pagination is using the startAt() in firebase query

Comment: so should I remove swipe refresh layout and use normal recyclerview and its adapter